# Xcode: distribute `Re-sign` step been hidden, how to get it back?

Tags: xcode, flutter, archive, distribute, apple-appclips

I have add App Clip into my flutter project, and then when I distribute it, the `Re-sign` step was somehow `missing`, because of this I cannot distribute the app.

Do you know which setting will cause this `Re-sign` step been `hidden` ?

[image]

Why cannot distribute ?
Because manually sign will get `No Eligible Profile` for app with app-clip

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I didn't find why the `automatically manager signing` choice step is missing.
2. I know how to fix `No Eligible Profile` , it just need to create clip bundle id in apple developer website, the automatic created profile not work for distribution with no reason.

So, the solution for distribution app with app Clip, just create your `xxxx.clip` bundle Id & related profiles with this `xxxx.clip` bundle id in apple developer website.

After that you should able to select a clip profile in distribution steps.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to make a new provisioning profile (or regenerate the one you were using) so it include the new capability which has been added by Xcode .

[...]

Xcode creates all required files for the options you choose, and adds a target for your App Clip with:

A scheme to build and run your App Clip and its tests.

**A new capability named On Demand Install Capable that adds the com.apple.developer.on-demand-install-capable entitlement.**

The Parent Application Identifiers Entitlement.

[...]

Comment: On Demand Install Capable  is  auto create when adding a app clip target. It's not the root cause.